# storing the values in temp variable before storing it in the desired location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

I have got a many to many relationship between these to models :-

`user.rb and city.rb`, so that I can access user.cities and city.users.

Once the user clicks add city I want to add those cities in the temp variable like this

```
temp = []
city = City.find(params[:id])
temp << city
```

then I want to iterate over the temp doing something like this `temp.each do |t|...`
then once the user clicks confirm my cities I want to add these cities in `user.cities`

What might be the best approach to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the best approach is to use javascript. Simply on click save cities ids in js, and on submit send them to appropriate action which will save them.

Comment: it can be done with ror but it is not right way to do it. But if u want...u can store temp values in session for example.

Comment: oh ok, can you please provide more detail on how to do it with js?

Comment: api.jquery.com also u can do it in rails view by creating form with checkboxes, check_box_tag "city_ids[]", city.id